# How to fix the position of a PopupPanel relative to the page when scrolling

Tags: java, gwt, popup, popuppanel

Essentially the popup panel stays a fixed position to the browser panel - where as I want it to scroll with the page.

I've tried setting the CSS element of the popup panel, with 'position: fixed !important' but no success.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386711/static-positioning-of-the-gwt-popuppanel) seems to explain a similar problem, but I'm still not exactly sure what the fix is supposed to be.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add  WindowScrollHandler by doing like this:

```
    Window.addWindowScrollHandler(new Window.ScrollHandler() {
       public void onWindowScroll(Window.ScrollEvent event) {
         popupPanel.setPopupPosition(event.getScrollLeft()+fromLeft,
                                      event.getScrollTop()+fromTop);
       }
    });
```